# django-comments add a new url and a view for comments?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-comments

i am newer and study django.when i install django_comments , i need add to add a new url and view for django_comments, but it don't work.

```
comments folder structure:
__init__.py  __pycache__/  forms.py  migrations/  models.py  templates/  urls.py  views.py

__init__.py:
def get_model():
    from comments.models import CommentModel
    return CommentModel

def get_form():
    from comments.forms import CommentForm
    return CommentForm
```

and forms.py and models.py is fine work.but when i add  urls.py, views.py and add the urls to main urls file. it don't work.

```
urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('delete/<int:comment_id>/', views.delete_own_comment, 'delete_own_comment'),
]


views.py
from .models import CommentModel

@login_required
def delete_own_comment(request, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(CommentModel, id=comment_id, site__pk=settings.SITE_ID)
    if comment.user == request.user:
        comment.is_removed = True
        comment.save()
```

but when i add `path('mycomments/', include('comments.urls'))` to main urls.py, it run strange errors. can anyone help me???

Comment: if i use djang-admin startapp and follow the regular step, it don't work, what happed to this???

Comment: Why do you add code to __init__.py? That's not necessary.

Comment: You should show what the actual error is.

Comment: Show the error traceback

Comment: follow the https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , it need to add something in __init__.py file.  and it raise "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"  error.

Comment: @jiechen You are not providing enough detail. ¿Did you create a project?¿Did you install django-contrib-comments properly?¿Are you trying to start a new app? ¿What is the stack error and when does it appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not

```
django-admin startapp myapp
```

It's

```
python manage.py startapp myapp
```

Provided that you created before a project with

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```